# Fairly complex LINQ to Entities query

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

I have two entities, assume they are called Container and Record. They have a master-child relationship: a 'container' can hold many records.

The Records table in the database has the following columns:

- Id
- Date
- Container_Id
- RecordType_Id

The Record entity does not have any navigation properties that back reference the Container.

I am writing a LINQ query for my repository that will retrieve ONLY the records for a container that have the *most recent* date for each RecordType_Id. All older records should be ignored.

So if a container has say 5 records, one for each RecordType_Id, with the date 24/May/2011. But also has another 5 records for each RecordType_Id but with the date 20/May/2011. Then only the first 5 with the 24/May date will be retrieved and added to the collection in the container.

I came up with an SQL query that does what I need (but maybe there is some more efficient way?):

```
select t.*
from Records t
    inner join (
        select Container_Id, RecordType_Id, max(Date) AS MaxDate
        from Records
        group by Container_Id, RecordType_Id ) g
    on t.Date = g.MaxDate
        and t.Container_Id = g.Container_Id
        and t.RecordType_Id = g.RecordType_Id 
order by t.Container_Id 
    , t.RecordType_Id 
    , t.Date
```

However I am struggling to translate this into a proper LINQ query. EF is already generating a fairly large query all by itself just to load the entities, which makes me unsure of how much of this SQL query is actually relevant to the LINQ query.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head:

```
var q = from c in Container
        from r in c.Records
        group r by r.RecordType.RecordType_Id into g
        select new
        {
            Container = c,
            RecordType_Id = g.Key,
            Records = from gr in g
                      let maxDate = g.Max(d => d.Date)
                      where gr.Date == maxDate
                      select gr
        };
```

Comment: Line 6 is saying the `c` symbol cannot be resolved. However, I'm not sure that ending up with an anonymous type is the correct solution. I need EF to be returning its tracked objects of Container as per normal. Except that each Container's "Records" collection is restricted to only include the most recent entries of each type.

Comment: Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way. Maybe I should be exposing the Container objects as they come. But make the Records collection be lazy loaded so that the consumer can append their deferred query logic to do the 'most recent records only' restriction.

Comment: You can work around the unresolved symbol by including it in the grouping. Don't let the anonymous type throw you off -- the `Records` property is a list of entities, just like you asked.

Comment: I think possibly my question was badly worded. It is my Container repository. Therefore it needs to be returning fully initialized Container objects. The Record objects must be filtered to only be the most recent ones, for each Container object.

Comment: You can return Container objects, if you want. But if you're asking to "filter" the Container.Records, then they *aren't fully initialized,* because real containers have more records.

Comment: This is making me believe even more than I'm doing this logic in the wrong place. That I should be exposing 'untainted' Container objects from the repository. Then, through deferred loading in EF, apply my query for the most recent Record's onto the Records collection property. Do you think this is the correct way?

Comment: The EF context is a representation of your DB. Your desire to have a filtered list of Records is an expression of a business need. Personally, I think the most correct thing to do here is partition business needs behind an entity service.

Answer (score 1):

Try using LinqPad, it helps you test linq queries easily. Even against an existing EF model (which is in your project). Visit http://www.linqpad.net/